# WIN10 openssh in cmd "ssh xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx sh xxx.sh" error ,cant read variable normaly

Tags: bash, ssh, cmd, openssh, openwrt

Im Win10 and installed the Openssh. My router is running **Openwrt**.The code is write via **BASH**

!!!The code is here!!!

```
flag1=1
option1_1="Its num1"
while [[ "$flag1" = "1" ]];do
read -n 1  -p "Please input num1    :" input1
case ${input1} in
    1)
      echo .
      read -n 1 -p "Your input is: $input1,comfirm?[1/0]" comfirm1
      if [[ "$comfirm1" = "1" ]];then
         echo .
         echo Your input is $input1,Goodbye
         flag1=0
      fi
  ;;
    *)
     echo Its not num1 ,please input again
     flag1=1
  ;;
esac
done
```

There is a .sh file in my router and i need to run it through the steps follow:

> Steps:

1. Win+R to open cmd.exe
2. type this command : ssh example@192.168.1.1 sh example.sh

And here the problem comes : it can't read the variable normally and cant output the words that i write in the file.

BUT,if i run this script use the command below,it would work normally:

> Steps:

1. Win+R to open cmd.exe
2. type : ssh example@192.168.1.1
3. type : sh example.sh

> Problems: (i have upload the video to Youtube :https://youtu.be/TPE9CjUQvxo)

It should read twich "1" and save to **$input1** and **$comfirm1**,but it actually only read correctly when i type "11",other input will cause it loop forever.

I have noticed something , but i dont know what can do:

> The things that i noticed:

1. When i use one command "ssh xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx sh xxx.sh",the cmd.exe window's title is still "C:\Winodws\system32\cmd.exe -ssh xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx sh test.sh".**BUT** when i break this command to two commands ,it change to "OpenSSH SSH client"
2. When i use one command,the code `read -n 1 -p "xxx"` wont work.it cant show the -p words or read only 1 character.

Anyone knows whats wrong and give me a advice to fix this ??